# Remove entire row given certain condition Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to know if there's a way for me to remove an entire row of a dataframe given a condition (An outlier) in one column?

Df

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Tree | 300 |
| Orange | 50 |
| Apple | 75 |
| Mango | 60 |
| Cherry | 1 |

In this case I would want to remove Cherry and Tree since they're outliers.

Comment: Are you asking about how to define the outliers?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: just to remove the entire row of the dataframe based on a condition for a column

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  Exactly what do you not understand from the tutorial sections on DF filtering and `drop`?

Comment: Maybe all you want to do is a `df.loc[~df[colname == value]]` to get what you want. Like Prune and other said, please go through pandas documentation for basic filtering options

Comment: The OP is presumably asking how to automatically recognize outliers, after you sort the dataframe by Value. They should define what they mean by outlier, but if they mean *"either the commonest or rarest"* as per this example, it's easy to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a subjective question. There is not a single definate way to do it. In fact there are multiple ways to do it. Use descriptive stats to build logic and then code it.

In this case I define the upper and lower limit and then filter using pandas mask. Code below

```
lower_limit=1
Upper_limit=100

df=df.assign(Value=df['Value'].where(df['Value'].between(lower_limit,Upper_limit))).dropna()



    Name  Value
1  Orange   50.0
2   Apple   75.0
3   Mango   60.0
4  Cherry    1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df[df.apply(lambda row: row['Value'] > lower_limit and row['Value'] < upper_limit, axis=1)]
```

`apply()` returns a boolean Series representing whether each `df['Value']` value is outliers. `df['Value'].between(lower_limit, upper_limit)` has the same effect.

Dataframe can accept a boolean indexing. The effect is to drop the coresponding False row, keep the coresponding True row.